# Kernel restarting running Ipython + PyMC

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, pymc

I'm getting an error in the Ipython Notebook saying `The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.` when I run the following code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import numpy as np
import pymc as pm
import pandas as pd

boston = load_boston()
features = ['INDUS', 'NOX', 'RM', 'TAX', 'PTRATIO', 'LSTAT']
df = pd.DataFrame(boston.data, columns=boston.feature_names)
X = np.array(df.ix[:, features])
y = boston.target

gamma = pm.Binomial('gamma', 1, 0.5, size=len(features))
var = pm.Lambda('var', lambda gamma=gamma: (1-gamma)*0.001 + gamma*10)
prec = pm.Lambda('prec', lambda var=var: 1.0/var)
b = pm.Normal('b', 0, prec)
int_ = pm.Normal('int_', 0, 0.01)
taue = pm.Gamma('taue', 0.1, 0.1)
mu = int_ + X[:,0]*b[0] + X[:,1]*b[1] + X[:,2]*b[2] + X[:,3]*b[3] + X[:,4]*b[4] + X[:,5]*b[5]
observed = pm.Normal('obs', mu, taue, observed=True, value=y)
M = pm.MCMC([observed, mu, int_, b, prec, var, gamma])
M.sample(10000, 500, 5)

pm.Matplot.plot(M)
```

In case it is relevant, I'm trying to reproduce an example of Bayesian variable selection from this [page](http://www.stat.ncsu.edu/research/bswg/seminars/breich.pdf) (WinBUGS code, page 14). Sometimes the kernel fails when I run `M.sample()` but most of the times the error appears when running `pm.Matplot.plot(M)`

I also tried to use `ipython qtconsole` but the result is the same. In `ipython`, it causes a segmentation fault. I'm using a conda environment with ipython 2.3.0, matplotlib 1.4.0, pandas 0.14.1, scikit-learn 0.15.2, pymc 2.3.4 and python 2.7.8. I created a new environment with ipython 3.0.0, but this issue remains.

Can anyone reproduce this issue?

**UPDATE**:

I tried this example in an EC2 instance using a fresh Anaconda environment and this is the only example I could find that gives errors. The only piece of code I needed to add was the following:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Therefore, I was basically running this in ipython:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%run model
```

where `model` is a file containing exactly the same code I posted initially. The errors change a bit. For example:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/ubuntu/model.py in <module>()
     16 int_ = pm.Normal('int_', 0, 0.01)
     17 taue = pm.Gamma('taue', 0.1, 0.1)
---> 18 mu = int_ + X[:,0]*b[0] + X[:,1]*b[1] + X[:,2]*b[2] + X[:,3]*b[3] + X[:,4]*b[4] + X[:,5]*b[5]
     19 observed = pm.Normal('obs', mu, taue, observed=True, value=y)
     20 M = pm.MCMC([observed, mu, int_, b, prec, var, gamma])

IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size -4611686018427387904

*** Error in `/home/ubuntu/anaconda/envs/env3/bin/python': double free or corruption (out): 0x00000000028a0b00 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Another one:

```
In [5]: %run model
 [-----------------100%-----------------] 10000 of 10000 complete in 17.7 sec/home/ubuntu/anaconda/envs/env3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:2499: VisibleDeprecationWarning: `rank` is deprecated; use the `ndim` attribute or function instead. To find the rank of a matrix see `numpy.linalg.matrix_rank`.
  VisibleDeprecationWarning)
Plotting int_
Plotting prec_0
Plotting prec_1
Plotting prec_2
Plotting prec_3
Plotting prec_4
Plotting prec_5
Plotting var_0
Plotting var_1
Plotting var_2
Plotting var_3
Plotting var_4
Plotting var_5
Plotting gamma_0
Plotting gamma_1
Plotting gamma_2
Plotting gamma_3
Plotting gamma_4
Plotting gamma_5
Plotting b_0
Plotting b_1
Plotting b_2
Plotting b_3
Plotting b_4
Plotting b_5
*** Error in `/home/ubuntu/anaconda/envs/env3/bin/python': double free or corruption (out): 0x00000000023dc940 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Again, similar to the error above:

```
In [6]: %run model
 [-----------------100%-----------------] 10000 of 10000 complete in 18.4 secPlotting var_0
*** Error in `/home/ubuntu/anaconda/envs/env3/bin/python': double free or corruption (out): 0x00000000035f0f10 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

This one occurs earlier:

```
In [13]: gamma = pm.Binomial('gamma', 1, 0.5, size=len(features))
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

And finally:

```
In [22]: M.sample(10000, 500, 5)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

At times, the code runs correctly and produces several plots. For comparison, I also ran [this example](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/wiki/NormalFit) and [this one](http://connor-johnson.com/2014/07/20/performing-incremental-updates-using-pymc/) without issues.

[This](http://pastebin.com/JBdNhayS) is the list of packages I installed in the conda environment.

Answer (score 0):

This runs just fine here, with Python 2.7.6 and IPython 3.0.0-dev. Can you try upgrading/changing your Matplotlib?

Comment: Using Ipython 2.3.0 and matplotlib installed from the master branch helps a little bit. When I run the code for the first time, it works. However, if I rerun the same code again, it restarts the kernel when plotting. I will install Ipython 3.0.0-dev again to see if that helps.

Comment: Ipython 3.0.0-dev doesn't help at all. Actually, sometimes restarts  before plotting and produces the same behavior as in ipython 2.3.0 after rerunning the code. Do you have something else different in your environment?

Comment: I posted an update on this issue using only Ipython. Maybe that helps to figure out this issue.